# Better failing message for asserting attributes of multiple objects in the collection

Tags: ruby, rspec

For asserting that object has expected attributes I come up with custom methods

```
def be_active_sales_order_with(quantity)
  expected = {
    :order_type => "sales",
    :activated_at => be_within(1.minute).of(Time.current),
    :quantity => quantity
  }

  have_attributes(expected)
end
```

When method above used with one object, failing message provide clearly formatted difference which attribute's value is different than expected.

Failing message:

expected # to have attributes {:order_type => "sales", :activated_at => (be within 300 of 2019-11-26 15:56:17), :quantity => 3} but had attributes {:order_type => "sales", :activated_at => 2019-11-24 15:56:17.000000000, :quantity => 3}
            Diff:
            @@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
             :order_type => "sales",
            -:activated_at => (be within 300 of 2019-11-26 15:56:17),
            +:activated_at => 2019-11-24 15:56:17.000000000,
             :quantity => 3,

```
it "creates single order" do
   # configuration for single order

   orders = create_order.call(quantity: 3)

   expect(orders.only).to be_active_sales_order_with(3)
end
```

But for case when multiple orders can be created failing message difficult to read without debugging failed test.

```
it "creates multiple orders" do
   # configuration for multiple order

   orders = create_order.call(quantity: 3)

   expect(orders).to contain_exactly(
     be_active_sales_order_with(3),
     be_active_sales_order_with(3),
     be_active_sales_order_with(3)
   )
end
```

Failing message:

expected collection contained:  [(have attributes {:order_type => "sales", :activated_at => (be within 300 of 2019-11-26 15:56:17), :quantity => 3})]
actual collection contained:    [#Order id: 885385454, customer_id: 367693892, topic: nil, created_at: "2019-..., segment_key: "9bf937d687eaff19", stock_id: nil, notified_by: nil, use_discount: false, user_id: 548091186]
the missing elements were:      [(have attributes {:order_type => "sales", :activated_at => (be within 300 of 2019-11-26 15:56:17), :quantity => 3})]
the extra elements were:        [#Order id: 885385454, customer_id: 367693892, topic: nil, created_at: "2019-..., segment_key: "9bf937d687eaff19", stock_id: nil, notified_by: nil, use_discount: false, user_id: 548091186]

How I can build more readable message, which provide readable difference between expected and actual object's attributes

Comment: what does the current diff look like?

Comment: @lacostenycoder, updated with current failing messages

Comment: Maybe have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660735/pretty-print-arrays-on-failure